# Footer to Header

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm new to UI-Grid and there is something I can not solve. I use:

```
    showGridFooter : true
```

and I see in the footer:

```
    Total Items: 16 ( Showing Items : 5)
```

I want instead to display that information in the footer you see in the header (top of the grid ).
Anyone know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can update header template to show those values.